# Make jQuery animation of large image moving smoother

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery seems to struggle when moving an image larger than 1600x1200 around on the page in an animated fashion.

Clearly, 'smoothness' of an animation is limited by the computer/browser, but is there a way that an animation can be made smoother in jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You can make this kind of animation significantly smoother by adding the following line of code to your script.

The human eye can only see around 33 frames per second. The default jQuery animation uses 1000/13 frames per second (around 76 fps). That's a lot more frames of animation than you need and each frame costs CPU time.

Changing it the interval from 13 to 33 makes your animations use around 30 frames per second which is just as smooth to the eye and more than twice as easy for the computer to render.

```
jQuery.fx.interval = 33;
```

Comment: The human eye can see a lot more then just 33 frames per second, that it can't it just a myth. To see for yourself you can chec out http://30vs60.com/dirt3.php for example. Still, your method might make the image move "smoother" if it doesn't get huge fps drops for trying to hard.